# List of combination python very large numbers

Tags: python, list

I need a list of all possible combinations of k out of n numbers for very large n. I run into the problem of my list size exceeding 500000 quickly, which python does not seem to handle very well. However, I would like to exceed that by hundreds of millions.
How do I handle that?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you need the whole list at once? Most of the things from `itertools` like `product`, etc produce generators for this exact reason.

Comment: There are O(n^k) k-combinations for O(n) numbers; just how much RAM do you have?

Comment: If you don't mind eating up your hard drive space and taking a while you could write to disk every say 100,000 combinations and empty your list.  It very much depends on what you will be using these combinations for though.

Comment: I do need the whole list at once, since it needs to be sorted in ascending order after some calculations. Maybe I could create new lists automatically after one is maxed out ?

Comment: Again, it's a question of resources rather than how long a list can be in Python. You say you need hundreds of millions of items – let's say best case scenario of 200 million items. If your computer runs out of RAM after 500,000 items then you'd need 400 times more RAM than you currently have to hold the entire list in memory.

Comment: And why does it need to be sorted in ascending order? Presumably for some further processing, but does that further processing really need it all to be in memory at once? Perhaps it is possible to determine the sort-order on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

DP won't work for very large number because storing such large size list would result in `MemoryError`. Idea is to do calculate things on fly and record the required values.

```
def comb(n, k):
        deno = 1
        num = 1
        result = 1
        #set the value of deno and num bounds
        if k > n - k:
                num_val = k + 1
                den_val = n - k
        else:
                num_val = n - k + 1
                den_val = k
        i = n
        #calculate n * (n - k) *....* (n-num_value))
        while i != num_val - 1:
                if i == 0:
                        result *= 1
                else:
                        result *= i
                if i == num_val:
                        num = result
                i -=1
        i = 0
        result = 1
        #calculate den_val! (factorial of denominator)
        while i != den_val + 1:
                if i == 0:
                        result *= 1
                else:
                        result *= i
                if i == den_val:
                        deno = result
                i += 1
        ans = num/deno
        return ans


if __name__ == "__main__":
        n = input("Enter n\n")
        k = input("Enter k\n")
        print(comb(n, k))
```

Complexity - O(max(k, n - k))